# Having data from another table put in into check constraint

Tags: sql, triggers, constraints

I have table say table1 with a colum say checkColumn,

now I want to put a check constraint to the field checkColumn  which would allow only data which is there in another table say table 2 for some conditions,

I tried this like this,

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD CHECK (checkColumn=(select field1 from table2 where field2='ABC') ) //the select is not scalar
```

but as I realized it doesn't allow sub-query string in the check condition,I searched a little and read I should use a foreign key,or trigger, or something else,but didn't really understand how to implement those examples here,so posting this as a separate question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not insert Sub Query into context of Check constraint. But here I would like give suggestion, You can use any trigger or function , You can use
foreign key constraint to check data dependency 
I would like to share one example with function.
e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_Check_Rollnumber (
    @Rollnumber INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT Rollnumber FROM Table_Student WHERE Rollnumber = @Rollnumber)
        return 'True'
    return 'False'
END
```

Now you can use this function in you Check context like,

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Fees 
    WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK_RollCheck
    CHECK (fn_Check_Rollnumber(Rollnumber) = 'True')
```

Comment: I came upon this approach but didn't quite uderstand how it would solve my issue,I mean when you pass 'Rollnumber' in the function call fn_Check_Rollnumber what is Rollnumber ? a column in table_fees ?

Comment: Yes Rollnumber is column in table_fees.

Comment: so what would it pass all roll numbers in table_fees one by one?

Comment: When you define this constraint then whenever you insert record that time check constraint check rollnumber using this function so automatically it will check one by one rollnumber during insertion process.