# SQL Server CHECK Constraint on value from a column not referenced explicitly

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, relational-database

Similar question has been asked here: [constraint check against values of foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841022/constraint-check-against-values-of-foreign-key) , and here [Having data from another table put in into check constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100700/having-data-from-another-table-put-in-into-check-constraint) , but it's not exactly what I mean (or whether there's any other way than a function).

My question is. Instead of referencing composite `FOREIGN KEY`, and then checking for the value of a referenced column via `CHECK` constraint, can I reference surrogate PK from `Table A` in `Table B` and check against a value of the column in `Table A` in a row identified uniquely by a surrogate PK from `Table A` called e.g. `[test_table_a_id]`

In other words. Can I have a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` in `Table B` without referencing specific column explicitly, but instead referencing id of a row and looking up the value in `Table A`. (Hope I am not being too consusing with the problem description)

```
-- ===============================
-- ---------- TABLE A ------------

CREATE TABLE [r_Test_Table_A](
    [test_table_a_id]   [int] IDENTITY(1,1) 

        CONSTRAINT [PK_r_test_table_a] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([test_table_a_id] ASC)    

,   [a_attribute_1]     [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL 
,   [a_attribute_2]     [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL 

,   CONSTRAINT [ak_r_Test_Table_A_a_attribute1_a_attribute_2] 
        UNIQUE ([a_attribute_1], [a_attribute_2])
)
-- ===============================
-- ---------- TABLE B ------------

CREATE TABLE [r_Test_Table_B](
    [test_table_b_id]   [int] IDENTITY(1,1) 

        CONSTRAINT [PK_r_test_table_b] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([test_table_b_id] ASC)

,   [b_attribute_1]     [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL 
,   [a_attribute_1]     [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL

        CONSTRAINT [ch_Test_Table_A_a_attribute_1] CHECK ([a_attribute_1] = 'Cookie')

,   [a_attribute_2]     [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL 

,   CONSTRAINT [fk_comp_r_Test_Table_B_r_Test_Table_A]
        FOREIGN KEY ([a_attribute_1], [a_attribute_2]) 
        REFERENCES [r_Test_Table_A]([a_attribute_1], [a_attribute_2])
)
```

Comment: About the only option here is to use a function. Of course in your code posted the only value allowed in tableb would be cookie but I don't think that is what you want. Perhaps you can share some actual values so it is more clear what you are trying to model here.

Comment: Hi. In this particular case, I know that I will want to accept only specific values. So e.g. 'Cookie' or if `a_attribute_1 > 5`. I was curious if there's another way, instead of not referencing 2 or 3 columns that make a compound / composite primary key in one table, have them as composite foreign key in second table, only for the sake of putting `CHECK` constraint on one of the attributes in the second table. I am sorry, but unfortunately, I cannot provide the real life code ATM (no access). But if function is the way to go, that's a good answer for me. As mentioned -asking of curiosity.

Comment: It doesn't have to be real values. But without some context it is really hard to visualize what you are trying to do. Use fruit or animal names. It doesn't matter but something that represents the problem.